# Chrome extension, get words surrounding selectionText

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a basic Chrome extension adding a menu when a user selects some text. 
I want to get the full sentence containing the selected text but I couldn't find a way to do that.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Selected text: %s",
  contexts:["selection"],
  onclick: doSmth,
});

function doSmth(info,tab) {
  console.log(info)
}
```

Output:

> {editable: false, frameId: 0, menuItemId: 9, pageUrl:
>   "http://www.liberation.fr/planete/2018/04/05/facebook-et-son-patron-en-operation-deminage_1641262",
>   selectionText: "siphonnées"}

Instead of "siphonnées", I would like to get the full sentence containing the selected word. Is it possible?

Comment: You'll have to do it in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) using standard DOM events and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I found is to run code injection directly from background script:

**background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Selected text: %s',
    contexts: ['selection'],
    onclick: doSmth,
});

function doSmth(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    }, result => {
        console.log(result[0]); // sentence
    });     
}
```

**inject.js**

```
(function() {   
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const chunk = selection.baseNode.textContent.slice(selection.baseOffset, selection.extentOffset);
    const re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\.\\s)((.(?!\\.\\s))*?)"+chunk+".*?\\.", 'g');
    return selection.baseNode.textContent.match(re);
})();
```

It takes selected text using `window.getSelection()` and then executes the regular expression in order to get a sentence.